# How can I fix "E:The package linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, xubuntu

`sudo apt update && sudp apt upgrade -y` now shows the error message

```
E:The package linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled. But I can't find an archive for it.
```

and nothing proceeds.
How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1299090/243321

Answer (score 1):

This package has been removed from the repositories.

Run

```
sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic
```

But make sure you have another kernel installed.

Comment: Sorry, all-apt-related seems broken. Same message occurs.

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/508370158/linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic_5.4.0-56.62_amd64.deb

download and install by

```
dpkg -i [file name]
```

after this, do what you need (update/upgrade/install... )

Comment: Oh, Thanx. Now it is fixed. Truely, truely, it is long time to NO APT UPDATE & UPGRADE...