# Risk of continuing to use kernel 5.4.0-56-generic that was removed from the repositories on 12-9-2020?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, kernel

On 12-2-2020 my computers received an update which included a new `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` version [5.4.0.56.62~18.04.50](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/linux-generic-hwe-18.04/5.4.0.56.62%7E18.04.50). This pulled in kernel 4.5.0-56.

On 12-9-2020 this version was deleted from the 18.04 repositories, "orphaning" the package and the associated kernel.

```
apt policy linux-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: 5.4.0.56.62~18.04.50
  Candidate: 5.4.0.56.62~18.04.50
  Version table:
 *** 5.4.0.56.62~18.04.50 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.54.60~18.04.48 500
        500 ssh:[local mirror]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.0.53.59~18.04.47 500
        500 ssh:[local mirror]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
```

What drove the removal of this kernel from the repositories, and is there a risk associated with continuing to use it?

Comment: The related USN seems to be https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4658-1 . The deleted status is [indicated here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04-edge/5.4.0.56.62~18.04.50). So it is a good question.

Comment: 5.4.0.58-generic brings back 5.4.0.56-xx bugs that were fixed in 5.4.0.56-62 until it vanished.

Comment: @cedesguin *"5.4.0.58-generic brings back 5.4.0.56-xx bugs that were fixed in 5.4.0.56-62"* - no, the [only effective change](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/510887924/linux_5.4.0-56.62_5.4.0-58.64.diff.gz) its contains is reverting a performance-motivated change to discard granularity, it is NOT meant to revert other (also potentially broken) bug fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [major regression](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1907262) with potential for **significant & likely data loss** was discovered after being distributed with a [security upgrade](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4658-1). The affected packages were removed from the Release files, as no immediate replacement was ready.

The bug appears to be triggered or caused by a performance-motivated change in the granularity of discard operations on md-backed software RAID1 and was replicated to lead to significant corruption during standard usage in typical **RAID10** setups.

> Impacted users may want to take action before the next scheduled run
> by downgrading the running kernel or temporarily disabling the fstrim
> job. -- [comment 12 on LP: #1907262](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/1850612)

Option 1 - continuing on the -56 version means:

- you will lose data if you are using such raid setup *(or if the original assessment that only those setups are affected was too narrow!)*
- you will eventually upgrade to a fixed version, as such version will be a assigned a higher version than the now orphaned one, automatic removals should deal with the old version then

Option 2 - Reverting to a previous version means:

- undoing the security upgrades it was bundled with **(bad!)**
- possibility of breaking automatic upgrades depending on your method (note you might not need to install/uninstall anything - just boot a different kernel from grub this one time!)

**Option 3 - Upgrading to the *(since released, but only being prepared for -proposed at the time this question was posed)* replacement -58 means:**

- you keep the security-motivated fixes
- you get everything in -56, [minus](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/510887924/linux_5.4.0-56.62_5.4.0-58.64.diff.gz) a small number of RAID1 patches likely being the reason for the regression
- if the -56 versions contained additional regression, those will be occur in -58 as well

**Recommendation:**

1. investigate whether the bug might have affected them and then
2. proceed using the -58 or following versions.

---

In any case, you are affected by two additional risks:

1. Possibility of future versions reintroducing this or similar bugs with less time to test for because Ubuntu is lagging behind upstream further because of this extra step (v5.4.73 has *two* upstream bug fixes to catch up to: v5.4.78, v5.4.83)
2. Possibility of future versions shipping broken dependencies because [replacing -oem&-oem-osp1 meta-packages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/1850612) with -generic happened [right before](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/509384145/linux-meta-hwe-5.4_5.4.0.54.60%7E18.04.48_5.4.0.56.62%7E18.04.50.diff.gz) so getting everything right in the nest version could plausibly cause some extra headache for maintainers.

---

<sub>How did I figure? There is a bot creating these hard to read but somewhat useful tracking bugs about all kernel releases, and someone marked the [tracking bug for the latest version 55.4.0-58.64](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1907390) as a `re-spin` to proceed without some of the usual tests. It appears to go back from the `v5.4.78` upstream to `v5.4.73`. We can assume [that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1907390) or some [later](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1907604) version *will* be promoted to the regular `-security` & `-updates` channel and applied to systems receiving upgrades just fine, even if they already have upgraded to the [orphaned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1905300) version.</sub>

Comment: Yowza! Thanks. Glad we don't use RAID.

Comment: If it really is as bad as it sounds, some people are going to wake up really surprised some time next week when they realize they do not use RAID1.. but their hosting provider does.

Comment: New kernel 5.4.0.58-generic pushed into repos tonight (12/11/20)